# How to make my functional Post component have certain linkable properties?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new to React and haven't learned how to use databases and other functions as of yet and this is my first major learning React project. I'm trying to make my functional Post component link/route to a /profile/uniqueTweetId. Here is my Post component, to show you how I have set it up.

```
function Post({displayName,username,verified,text,image,avatar,comments,shares,likes,twitterId}) {
   return (
    <div className = "post">
        <div className = "post__avatar">
            <Avatar src={avatar}  />        
        </div>
        <div className = "post__body">
            <div className = "post__header">
                <div className = "post__headerText">
                    <h3>
                        {displayName} {""}
                        <span className = "post_headerSpecial"> 
                            {verified && <VerifiedUserIcon className="post__badge" />} @
                            {username}
                        </span>
                    </h3>
                </div>
                <div className = "post__headerDescription">
                    <p>{text}</p>
                </div>
                <img src= {image} alt= "" />
                <div className = "post__footer">
                    <span className ="post__chatSpan"> <ChatBubbleOutlineIcon className = "post__chatStyling" fontSize="small" onClick={() => setCommentCount(commentCount + 1)}   />
                        <span className = "post__chatFormating">{comments + commentCount} </span>
                    </span> 

                    <span className ="post__repeatSpan"> <RepeatIcon className = "post__repeatStyling" fontSize="small" onClick={() => setRepeatCount(repeatCount + 1)} />
                        <span className = "post__repeatFormating">{shares + repeatCount}</span>
                    </span>

                    <span className ="post__favoriteSpan"> <FavoriteBorderIcon className = "post__favoriteStyling" fontSize="small" onClick={() => setLikeCount(likeCount + 1)} />
                        <span className = "post__favoriteFormating">{likes + likeCount}</span>
                    </span>
                    <PublishIcon fontSize="small" />
                </div>
           </div> 

        </div>
    </div>

)
}

export default Post;
```

The problem arises when I render, the Post in my functional Feed component.

```
function Feed() {
  
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className= "feed">
        <Switch>

        </Switch>
          {/* Header */}
          <div className= "feed__header">
              <h2>Home</h2>
          </div>

          {/* TweetBox */}
          <TweetBox />
          

          {
            listOfPosts.map(function (post) {
              return ( 
                  < Post 
                    displayName= {post.displayName}
                    username= {post.username}
                    verified= {post.verified}
                    text= {post.text}
                    avatar = "blah"
                    image = "blah"
                    comments = {post.comments}
                    shares = {post.shares}
                    likes = {post.likes}
                    twitterId ={post.twitterId}
                    />
                  );
              })
          }
      </div>
    </Router>
  )
}

export default Feed;
```

which listOfPosts is my array of hard coded "Post" prop variables that I'm currently looping through to render each post, so that in the future I could push the posts inside the array into a database when I'm ready. I'm struggling because I don't understand how to use React router in this context, because if I use Link inside the map function, All the props become a link, and I lose the functionality of my counters. I was hoping for ideas on how to attack this problem and to make my components work like an actual twitter post. Sorry for the long post it's my first StackOverflow question. Thank you again, any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where are you trying to put a link to "/profile/<twitterId>"? Or is that your question, where to put a `Link` component?

Comment: I guess where to put it, and if I use a Link components how to make everything but the comments, shares, and likes so I can keep the functionality of the counters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "keep the functionality of the counters", a link shouldn't effect that at all, but you likely just need a `<Link to={`/profile/${twitterId}`}>Profile</Link>` somewhere in your `Post` component.

Comment: Interesting, so I'm assuming after I just use some inline styles to get rid of the underscores, and a hovering css style to get the color background and functionality of a standard twitter post. If that seems correct?

Comment: Sure, you can style your links.  Alternatively you can use a button (or some other element) with an `onClick` handler to do a `history.push` to the profile page, but don't forget to apply the `role="link"` attribute for accessibility.

Comment: I'll give it a try in the next few hours, and return with my results. Thank you for your help so far

Comment: I was able to link some of the javascript props inside the Post component, using a method like this for example.

Comment: What did you do? Did you mean to update your question with the example?